# can't pass element from one function to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i am trying to pass changed value in `AddEventListener` function as well as counter of the loop to change subtotal in my `<td>` when user change the input value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var QuantityButtons = document.getElementsByName('quantity')
    for (let i = 0; i < QuantityButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = QuantityButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }
})

function quantityChanged(){
    var input = event.target
    console.log('max value',input.max)
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    if (input.value >= input.max){
        input.value = input.max
    }
    var input_value = input.value
    updateSubtotal(input_value)
}
function updateSubtotal(input_value){
    var priceElement = document.getElementsByClassName('subtotal')[0].innerHTML
    console.log(input_value)
}
```

```html
{% if items %}
<div class="small-container cart-page">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Condition</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in items %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="cart-info">
                    <a id="detail-link" href="{% url 'product_detail' item.product.id %}"><img src="{{item.product.image}}" alt="none"></a>
                    <div>
                        <p>{{item.product.title}}</p>
                        <p><small>by: {{item.product.author}}</small></p>
                        <small>Price: ${{item.product.price}}</small>
                        <br>
                        <a href="{% url 'delete_from_cart' item.product.id %}">Remove</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><input name="quantity" type="number" value="{{ item.quantity }}" max="{{item.product.quantity}}" min="0"></td>
            <td>{{ item.product.condition }} </td>
            <td class="subtotal">{{item.product.price}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}


    </table>
    <div class="total-price">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td id="total"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% else %}
<div id="image-only"></div>
{% endif %}
```

so in my `updateSubtotal` function instead of [0] element i want to get to the same element as in first function but i dont know how to pass it .

When i pass it in `button.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged(i))` the event in `function quantityChanged()` is not defined.

Any idea??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is the wrong way to pass arguments. You should do something like :- `button.addEventListener('change', function () {quantityChanged(i)})`

Comment: You're missing the `event` parameter: `function quantityChanged(event)`

Comment: @user12137152 thats is what i was looking for. Thank you very much